# Dynamically adding hierarchical(Tree) rows (with form fields) in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, treeview, hierarchical

I have a requirement to dynamically add rows with 5 select box and Add and Delete buttons. When I click on Add, a child row should be generated with the same set of select boxes and buttons. It can go deep nested as well. Delete should delete the row and if it has child rows, the child rows must also get deleted. The view must be hierarchical data table or grid. Could someone let me know if there is an implementation for this which I can extend? The implementation is in Angular 2/4.

Comment: What is your current progress?

Comment: I was able to do complete this without a table or grid in Angular 4. Like adding the same row dynamically on click of Add. But what I want is to actually generate the rows in tree structure so that I know the hierarchy.

Comment: Don't expect someone to build this for you from scratch.

Comment: Thank you!!! All I wanted was to check if there is a component available for Tree Grid in Angular2/4. I have developed the current one from scratch.